# "member function already defined or declared" - What does that mean?

Tags: c++, sorting, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I am writing a program, which should list some tasks, order them by date and so on.

The last thing I did was, to add the "sort by date" functionality. Before that everything worked fine. If I run my code now, I get the following error message (I get this message 3 times)

```
member function already defined or declared
```

I don't understand, what is wrong. The code that triggers the error looks like this:

```
static bool compareDates(entry e1, entry e2) { 
    string s1 = e1.date;
    string s2 = e2.date;

    int day_1 = atoi(s1.substr(0, 2).c_str());
    int month_1 = atoi(s1.substr(3, 2).c_str()); // dd.mm.yyyy
    int year_1 = atoi(s1.substr(6, 4).c_str());

    int day_2 = atoi(s2.substr(0, 2).c_str());
    int month_2 = atoi(s2.substr(3, 2).c_str());
    int year_2 = atoi(s2.substr(6, 4).c_str());

    if (year_1 > year_2) return true;
    else if (year_1 < year_2) return false;

    if (month_1 > month_2) return true;
    else if (month_1 < month_2) return false;

    if (day_1 > day_2) return true;
    else if (day_1 < day_2) return false;

    return true;
}

// ... some code in between ...

private: void sortList() { // in the class
    sort(john_lines.begin(), john_lines.end(), compareDates);
    sort(tomas_lines.begin(), tomas_lines.end(), compareDates);
    sort(bernd_lines.begin(), bernd_lines.end(), compareDates);
    sort(peter_lines.begin(), peter_lines.end(), compareDates);
}
```

I tried to run this code without the rest, and it worked. Does somebody know what is wrong with my application? Here is the error message I receive:

```
Error 1 error C2535: 'void V2::MainWindow::sortList(void)' : member function already defined or declared
<path>\MainWindow.h 422 1 V2

Error 14 error C2535: 'void V2::MainWindow::sortList(void)' : member function already defined or declared
<path>\MainWindow.h 422 1 V2

Error 28 error C2535: 'void V2::MainWindow::sortList(void)' : member function already defined or declared
<path>\MainWindow.h 422 1 V2
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <exception>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct entry {
    string text;
    string date;
    bool finished;
};

vector< entry > john_lines;

bool compareDates(entry e1, entry e2) {
    string s1 = e1.date;
    string s2 = e2.date;

    int day_1 = atoi(s1.substr(0, 2).c_str());
    int month_1 = atoi(s1.substr(3, 2).c_str()); // dd.mm.yyyy
    int year_1 = atoi(s1.substr(6, 4).c_str());

    int day_2 = atoi(s2.substr(0, 2).c_str());
    int month_2 = atoi(s2.substr(3, 2).c_str());
    int year_2 = atoi(s2.substr(6, 4).c_str());

    if (year_1 > year_2) return true;
    else if (year_1 < year_2) return false;

    if (month_1 > month_2) return true;
    else if (month_1 < month_2) return false;

    if (day_1 > day_2) return true;
    else if (day_1 < day_2) return false;

    return true;
}

int main() {    
    entry e;

    e = { "clean the window", "12.08.2016", true };
    john_lines.push_back(e);
    e = { "tidy the room", "14.06.2012", false };
    john_lines.push_back(e);
    e = { "sort the papers", "16.08.2016", false };
    john_lines.push_back(e);
    e = { "writing the code for this application", "19.08.2018", false };
    john_lines.push_back(e);
    e = { "test period of this applicaition", "30.11.2020", false };
    john_lines.push_back(e);

    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "- before:                                                                     -" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<john_lines.size(); i++) {
        e = john_lines.at(i);
        string finished = (e.finished) ? "(  done  ) " : "(not done) ";
        cout << finished << e.date << " - " << e.text << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    sort(john_lines.begin(), john_lines.end(), compareDates);

    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "- after:                                                                      -" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<john_lines.size(); i++) {
        e = john_lines.at(i);
        string finished = (e.finished) ? "(  done  ) " : "(not done) ";
        cout << finished << e.date << " - " << e.text << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the part inside the functions relevant? Is the part outside the functions relevant? Please provide a minimal but complete example.

Comment: Try removing line 83: `private: void sortList();`

Comment: The guidelines requiere that you extract a minimal example first, which also has reasons. It forces you to focus on the relevant parts and in quite a few cases you will find the mistake yourself. Then, post that minimal amount of code inline here, because pastbins have a limited lifetime and the whole info should be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is declared in Line 83, and probably defined it elsewhere.

```
private: void sortList();
```

You have redefined it in Line 422

```
private: void sortList() {
        sort(john_lines.begin(), john_lines.end(), compareDates);
        sort(tomas_lines.begin(), tomas_lines.end(), compareDates);
        sort(bernd_lines.begin(), bernd_lines.end(), compareDates);
        sort(peter_lines.begin(), peter_lines.end(), compareDates);
}
```

Comment: This will be much harder to help out as it is a run time problem. Check `*_vec.erase` around lines 120 to 130. You might be passing an invalid iterator, maybe trying to erase more than what you have in the vector.